# help with jquery table sorter

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) jQuery plugin to work, but haven't been successful. Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

I am receiving the "jquery loaded" alert box and triple checked the path to the tablesorter javascript file.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"  />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            if (jQuery) {
                alert("jquery loadedd");
            }
            $("#foobar").tablesorter();
        }
    );
    </script>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<table id="foobar" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Nuno</td>
            <td>20</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried it with more table rows? have you inspected the elements and made sure the appropriate classes are applied? i believe it is .header, .headerSortDown, .headerSortUp by default.

Comment: I've tested this in a fiddle with more data and it works without issue (http://jsfiddle.net/sgbVS/  -- i dont have a style sheet attached, but click on the column headers <th>'s) would you happen to have a live example?

Comment: it is working in fact. i thought it would automatically appear with the layout shown on the author site. thanks for your help ;P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm glad its working. The css through me for a quick loop at first too.

be sure to grab the authors css, but mainly the classes you need to style are .header, .headerSortDown, and .headerSortUp You can also customize the classes the table receives. I also found the tablesorters widget system to be nice and easily customizable. An example of a default widget is zebra striping.

Answer (score 0):

Another tricky thing I just learned is that you seam to need to have thead and tbody elements in your markup (which you had, but this post turned up on a google search and this may help others). Migrating old code and using an in-browser inspector can fool you for a while ;)